# How to flatten map values using java streams

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I am new to Java streams and have a problem at hand. I have a map like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> specialProductsMap
```

And i want to flatten the map values to a set which contains all the String values in lists in the `specialProductsMap`. How can i do this using Java Streams?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may use the `flatMap` operator to get this thing done. Here's how it looks.

```
Set<String> valueSet = specialProductsMap.values().stream()
    .flatMap(List::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 4):

First Obtain the list of values from map then use stream api like this

```
Set<String> setOfString = specialProductsMap.values().stream().flatMap(list->list.stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Or Like this Using Method reference

```
Set<String> setOfString = specialProductsMap.values().stream().flatMap(List::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to stream your values :

```java
Stream<List<String>> myStream = specialProductsMap.values().stream();
```

Then flatten it :

```java
Stream<String> myData = myStream.flatMap(List::stream);
```

Then collect in a set :

```java
Set<String> = myData.collect(Collectors.toSet());
```